# Use the string stored in a Variant in an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to use the values inside of a Variant.

An example of the code:

```
Dim Holder as Variant

Holder = "1,1,1,1,1"
```

Later I will be using this Variant inside of an `Array()`.

The Declaration is like this:

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(Holder)
```

There was an error right after this

> Run-Time Error '5':
>   Invalid Procedure call or argument*

Is there a way to insert the Variant's values into `Array(<Here?)`.

Holder's value is not constant, it will change depending on a function I created.

Comment: Use `Split(holder,",")` rather than `Array()`

Comment: `Holder = Array(1,1,1,1,1)` or `Holder = Array("1","1","1","1","1")` (probably the former as the 1's are true integers for the [QueryTable.TextFileColumnDataTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221726%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

Comment: As I already told and showed you, Split () is the way to go and have an array out of a string. And the "separator" doesn't survive in the array so when "elements" are numbers (like in your case) it's convenient to use a space as separator in the "source" string so that you can use Split(source) function without having to explicitly pass the separator charachter as its second parameter, being the space the default one

Comment: @user3598756 I have followed your method but I'm still getting the same error with it. 

When I use `Split()` or `Array()` they still giving me the same error when it is used in 

`.TextFileColumnDataType = Split(Holder)` or  `.TextFileColumnDataType = Array(Holder)`

I know that **Split()** is is working but it just won't be accepted after this line of code `.TextFileColumnDataType` and I couldn't just write it like this `.TextFileColumnDataType = Holder` even when I have "Split"ed `Holder`

Comment: so follow Mrig method you already accepted as answer in a previous and related question

Answer (score 0):

A way to accomplish this is as suggested in comments, using the `split`
If you are getting an error I am guessing that you are not using it correctly.
This is how the code should look.

```
 dim i as long
 dim var
      Holder = "1,1,1,1,1"
      var = Split(Holder,",")
    for i = 0 to 4
          .TextFileColumnDataTypes = var(i)
    next i
```